# Why can I successfully cast a Swift array struct to AnyObject?

Tags: swift

As far as I know, Swift objects should conform to `AnyObject` and `Any`, while structs should only conform to `Any`.

```
//Tested with Swift 5.0

class Car {
    var name = ""
}

let myArray = [Car]()

let example1 = myArray as? AnyObject
let example2 = myArray as AnyObject

print(example1 != nil) //true
print(example2 != nil) //true
```

Why are both examples `true`?
To my knowledge `example1` should be `nil` and `example2` should not even compile.

Where is my misconception?

Comment: When comparing a non-optional value (example2) to != nil you always get true, irrelevant of the type of the value

Comment: Read my answer, please. It's more complicated when rob's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast `Array<_>` to `AnyObject` on Apple platforms because of Objective-C bridging.

The Swift compiler and runtime on Apple platforms can convert any Swift type to some sort of reference object. In general, a value type is converted to (wrapped in) an instance of `__SwiftValue` which is a subclass of `NSObject`. However, the Swift standard library uses some undocumented language features to customize certain conversions:

- An `Array<_>` casts to an `NSArray`.
- A `Dictionary<_, _>` casts to an `NSDictionary`.
- A `String` casts to an `NSString`.
- A number or boolean casts to an `NSNumber`.

Comment: I amwasaware that I can cast String to NSString, etc. But never thought about the fact, that this "extends" to super classes / protocols as well. Thanks for you answer.

Comment: @rob. I know that your answer was approved. I read the source code, but, please, provide more detailed information. I mean proofs

Comment: @robmayoff so? What I should find? I know that this wraps into _SwiftValue. But saying 'Array converts to NSArray' is totally incorrect for value types.

Comment: you answer may confuse a lot of people.

Comment: I apparently answered florieger’s question to his satisfaction. I don’t understand what you’re asking. “Array converts to NSArray” is indisputable, because (for example) `[123] as AnyObject is NSArray` evaluates to `true`. If you want more detail, please post your own top-level question, explaining what you don’t understand about my answer.

Comment: @robmayoff you can convert. yes. But this is not a bridging.

Comment: You can call it whatever you want. I’m going to call it “bridging” because [that is what the Swift language authors call it.](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/BridgeObjectiveC.swift)

Comment: And class Car should convert into SwiftObject. Not a SwiftValue.

Comment: I agree. I don’t see where I said otherwise, but perhaps I’m overlooking something.

Comment: in your link, they provide 'box' word. 'boxing' and 'unboxing' is more appropriate for such cast. As I provided in my answer

Answer (score 0):

As I understood such implementation,

when this code is executed,

```
let example1 = myArray as? AnyObject
```

your `myArray` is wrapped by an entity with a reference count.
being myArray a struct (the other value types too) it doesn't have got a reference count. At this moment the value is moved to the heap. 
When you cast to an array again, you take this value object from its wrapper.

Regarding documented information,

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array

Bridging from Array to NSArray takes O(1) time and O(1) space if the array’s elements are already instances of a class or an @objc protocol; otherwise, it takes O(n) time and space.

So, the statement 'An Array<_> casts to an NSArray' is not actually valid.
It's more complicated for value types.

More appropriate is to call it 'boxing' and 'unboxing'

Comment: “An `Array<_>` casts to an `NSArray`” is actually valid, according to the behavior of the Swift compiler and the text of *The Swift Programming Language*. `[x] as AnyObject is NSArray` evaluates to `true` for all `x`, and [*The Swift Programming Language*](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html#ID388) defines this as a “cast”: “The `as` operator performs a cast when it is known at compile time that the cast always succeeds, such as upcasting or bridging.”

Answer (score -1):

You're doing a downcasting, the compile doesn't complain because car class implicitly conforms to the AnyObject protocol.

Is the same as you did `let example1: AnyObject = myArray as? AnyObject` That you can see why the 2 tests are True.

Comment: He didn’t cast a `Car`. He cast an `Array<Car>`. `Array` is a generic `struct`, not a `class`.